# How to convert list of strings to integer indexes?

Tags: python-3.x, list, indexing

I have a list like this:

```
 lst = [['ab', 'bc', 'cd'], ['dg', 'ab']]
```

I want to build a string indexer and convert it into:

```
 lst_converted = [[1,2,3], [4,1]]
```

Do some processing on the converted list and then if the output is [[3], [2]]

```
 lst_output = [['cd'], ['ab']]
```

Here,

```
  'ab' = 1
  'bc' = 2
  'cd' = 3
  'dg' = 4
```

Strings can be arbitrary and not necessarily characters. How to do this?

Comment: `Strings can be arbitrary and not necessarily characters` ... then you should give a more general example.

Comment: modified the example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a list comprehension along with a dictionary to map the string literals to integer values:

```py
d = {}
d['ab'] = 1
d['bc'] = 2
d['cd'] = 3
d['dg'] = 4

lst = [['ab', 'bc', 'cd'], ['dg', 'ab']]
lst_converted = [[d[y] for y in x] for x in lst]
print(lst_converted)  # [[1, 2, 3], [4, 1]]
```